# How can I make a ProgressDialog be cancelable by the back button but not by a screen tap?

Tags: android, screen, android-asynctask, progressdialog, tap

I would like to make a `ProgressDialog` cancelable by the back button but not by a screen tap.  Currently I use `setCancelable(true)`.

However, in some newer devices a tap on the screen also cancels the `ProgressDialog`. I'd like to disable the screen tap action while the `ProgressDialog` is shown.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use [setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside%28boolean%29).

Comment: I'll do this as soon as I get in tomorrow and post my progress.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you ! Saved me a lot of time ! The [setCancellable(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setCancelable(boolean)) method of the **AlertDialog Builder** is misleading; it only handles the dialog being cancelled from the back button. The **cancelable by touch** property should also be available from the builder !

Answer (score 3):

Try this it will help you:

```
ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(main.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
pd.setCancelable(true);`
```