# How to make a ProgressDialog uncanceled in Android

Tags: android, progressdialog

How to make the `ProgressDialog` uncanceled in android, when loading I don't want to have the ability to abort the `ProgressDialog`

```
        SingupBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
        SingupBar.setMessage("Chargement...");
        SingupBar.setIndeterminate(false);

        SingupBar.show();
        .......
        SingupBar.hide();
```

and is this the best way to use it ?

Comment: hard to catch what do you mean, but you can set .setCancelable(true);

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a ProgressDialog be cancelable by the back button but not by a screen tap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100223/how-can-i-make-a-progressdialog-be-cancelable-by-the-back-button-but-not-by-a-sc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dialog.setCancelable(false);`

```
    SingupBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
    SingupBar.setMessage("Chargement...");
    SingupBar.setIndeterminate(false);
    SingupBar.setCancelable(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

**@Yasser B.**

You can and to prevent dismiss dialog box on outside touch use this

```
 SingupBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Finally,

```
SingupBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
SingupBar.setMessage("Chargement...");
SingupBar.setIndeterminate(false);
SingupBar.setCancelable(false);
SingupBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

For more info you can visit

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable(boolean)

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom dialog with progress bar in it use this....

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(getBaseContext());
d.setCancelable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The setCancelable property does it

```
     ProgressDialog   progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
     progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
     progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...please wait");
     progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
     progressDialog.show();
```

set it to false.